# Upload a file with a file.write interface

Tags: python

I've never seen this in Python and I'm interested if there is anything out there that will allow you to send files (for example HTTP PUT or POST) with a write interface? I've only ever seen a read interface where you pass a filename or `file` object (urllib, requests etc)

Of course I may have never seen this for good reason, which I'd also be interested to know.

Answer (score -1):

While it might look like it would make sense at a high level, let's try to map the file interface to HTTP verbs:

```
file interface   http
------------------------
read             GET
                 HEAD
------------------------
write            POST
                 PUT
                 PATCH
------------------------
?                DELETE
                 OPTIONS
```

As you can see, there's no clear mapping between the file interface and the set of HTTP verbs that are required for any RESTful interface. Of course, you could likely hack an implementation together that only  uses `GET` (read) and `POST` (write), but that will break the second you need to extend it to support any other HTTP verbs.

**Edit based on comments:**

I haven't tried it myself, but it seems like deep down (http/client.py), if data implements `read`, it will read it as such:

```
        while 1:
            datablock = data.read(blocksize)
            if not datablock:
                break
            if encode:
                datablock = datablock.encode("iso-8859-1")
            self.sock.sendall(datablock)
```

Do note the possible performance hit in doing this though:

```
# If msg and message_body are sent in a single send() call,
# it will avoid performance problems caused by the interaction
# between delayed ack and the Nagle algorithm. However,
# there is no performance gain if the message is larger
# than MSS (and there is a memory penalty for the message
# copy).
```

So yes, you *should* be able to pass in a file object as the `data` param.

Comment: I don't think the http verb matters. If there is data to send with the request, at the moment the network buffer is filled by reading from a file. I just want to fill it by writing to it. I think [c# has a writable stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getrequeststream.aspx) for web requests, I just wondered if it is possible in python

Comment: I don't understand sorry - Do you suggest I directly interact with the socket to send data? The `send` / `sendall` are basically the same as a write interface I'm after.

Comment: I'm looking for a library that I can send data with a write interface rather than passing something with a `read` method which is how all the libraries I've ever come across in python work. This doesn't really answer my question. (I didn't down vote though)